# c++ Continued fraction evaluation using boost/math

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use the boost `boost/math/tools/fraction.hpp` to evaluate a continued fraction, however I can't even make the examples provided in the boost documentation work (the provided source example does not compile).

Can anyone provide a working example (e.g. the `golden_ratio` example discussed in the boost documentation would be great). The boost documentation on this particular topic is scant, or at least not clear to me, a relative `C++` newbie. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what example exactly are you trying to compile and what are the error messages?

Comment: Thank you. It was the first example that didn't compile, but the answer provided by Adrien solved that, so the problem is now solved.

Answer (score 2):

The following snippest works for me :

```
#include <boost/math/tools/fraction.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> struct golden_ratio_fraction
{
    typedef T result_type;
    T operator()() { return 1.0; }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    golden_ratio_fraction<double> frac;

    double res = boost::math::tools::continued_fraction_a(
        frac, std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon());

    cout << "Res : " << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There is one mistake in the boost example, they wrote 
`T operator() { return 1.0; }` instead of `T operator()() { return 1.0; }`.

Then, it's important to note that you have to instanciat the object "frac". You can't write :

```
double res = boost::math::tools::continued_fraction_a(
            golden_ratio_fraction<double>(), std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
```

Enjoy boost !

Comment: Thank you very much! Your snippet also works for me. I think it is obvious how much of a newbie I am that I didn't notice the error in the example. Thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: As a follow up, is possible to evaluate a continued fraction where the coefficients are std::complex<double>? I can't get it to work in that particular case, although the template works fine for standard types such as float or double.

Comment: In the boost documentation they explicity said that this works for "arithmetic types or pair of arithmetic types". And when we look to the implementation they wrote thinks like that : "while(fabs(delta - 1) > factor)". So this kind of line will not works with an std::complex type.

Comment: Thank you so much. I should do a more thorough read of the documentation.